# How to create a file name with UTF-8 characters in Cygwin

Tags: bash, utf-8, cygwin

Using a shell script run under Cygwin, I want to create a file name which contains Danish characters (Ø, Æ, and Å). I have a bash script which basically does this: echo "some data" > "file name with Danish letters.txt". After running such script, all Danish letters look like a dot in the file name. I have tested this using Cygwin 32 under Windows 7 and Cygwin 64 under Windows 10. The locale command produces the following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Running:

```
echo "rødgrød" | od -ctx1
```

produces this:

```
0000000   r 303 270   d   g   r 303 270   d  \n
         72  c3  b8  64  67  72  c3  b8  64  0a
0000012
```

Here is an example of how the bash script looks like:

```
echo "some data" > "Peter Sørensen.txt"
```

The letter ø looks like a dot when I look at the created file name in Windows. Here is a screenshot of the file name:

[image]

In cygwin, running the ls command results in this message:

```
ls: cannot compare file names ‘Peter S\370rensen.txt’ and ‘test.sh’: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

And here is a screenshot of how this file name looks like in cygwin terminal after running the ls command:

[image]

Comment: This depends on the Windows file system's code page support. I would guess your Windows is configured to use code page 1252 and that Cygwin knows this and translates the code points, but there is a lot of speculation here. In bash, what does `echo "rødgrød" | od -ctx1` produce? Is it different from https://ideone.com/8dLHuX?

Comment: Also, what's the output of `locale -a`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a [mcve].

Comment: `‘S$'\370'rensen’` is one-byte encoding, e.g. `cp1252` (octal `\370` is hexadecimal `0xF8`). In UTF-8, `echo ‘S$'\xC3\xB8'rensen’` returns `‘Sørensen’`. Check the script encoding…

Comment: Thank you all. My script was encoded in ANSI but once I changed the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM everything works as expected.